# Return matches from array if contains specific words

Tags: javascript, arrays, multiple-matches

I have an array that contains several countries followed by an option and a number.

0 " UK One 150 "

1 " Switzerland Two 70 "

2 " China Two 120 "

3 " Switzerland One 45 "

4 " China One 90 "

5 " UK Two 50 "

This is how I get the array using xpath:

```
    var iterator = document.evaluate('//xpath/li[*]', document, null, XPathResult.UNORDERED_NODE_ITERATOR_TYPE, null);

try {
  var thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
  var arrayList = [];

  while (thisNode) {
    arrayList.push(thisNode.textContent); 
    thisNode = iterator.iterateNext();
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < arrayList.length; i++) {
    console.log(arrayList[i]);
  }   
} catch (e) {
  dump('Error' + e);
}
arrayList
```

What I would like to do with this array is to sort out and return only the matches. E.g. I would like for it to return only UK and China, so the array would look like this.

0 " UK One 150 "

1 " China Two 120 "

2 " China One 90 "

3 " UK Two 50 "

Comment: You can use the filter method.

Comment: Please share the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can do it like this with help of `sort()` `filter()` and `regex`**

What i did is first filter all the elements which contains either `UK` or `China`.

Now on this filtered array i need to capture the number using regex and sorted them in descending order.

```js
let arr =[
"UK One 150 ",
"Switzerland Two 70 ",
"China Two 120 ",
"Switzerland One 45 ",
"China One 90 ",
"UK Two 50 ",
];

let op = arr.filter(e=> 
    /(UK|China)/gi.test(e))
   .sort((a,b)=>{a.match(/\d+/g) - b.match(/\d+/g)}
 );
 
console.log(op);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your array using the regular expression and then sort the result on the numeric value.

```js
let data =["UK One 150 ","Switzerland Two 70 ","China Two 120 ","Switzerland One 45 ","China One 90 ","UK Two 50 "],
  result = ((arr) => data.filter(s => new RegExp(arr.join('|'), 'ig').test(s)))(['UK', 'China'])
          .sort((a,b)=> +a - +b);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a form of [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) to "decorate" the data by extracting the name of the country, and the number using a [`array.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) and regex.

Now you can filter by the country, sort by the number, and extract the str using another map.

```js
const arr =[
"UK One 150 ",
"Switzerland Two 70 ",
"China Two 120 ",
"Switzerland One 45 ",
"China One 90 ",
"UK Two 50 ",
];

const pattern = /^(\S+)\D+(\d+)/;
const requestedCounteries = new Set(['UK', 'China']);

const result = arr
  .map(str => str.match(pattern)) // ['UK One 150 ', 'UK', '150']
  .filter(([,country]) => requestedCounteries.has(country))
  .sort(([,,a], [,,b]) => +b - +a)
  .map(([str]) => str);
 
console.log(result);
```